# How to calculate the y coordinate of a rectangle without transforms in Inkscape?

Tags: svg, inkscape

Imagine I have an [Inkscape file](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s35/sh/13548dcc-2b50-4b9c-b383-e8c22536b397/2e51c7acc1d33630008dc28504232761) with the following rectangle:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to calculate the Y coordinate reported by Inkscape (`596.654`).

How can I do it (manually) ?

I tried this:

1. The top of the page seems to have a Y coordinate of 744.
2. I subtract from that number the y coordinate of the rectangle in the XML editor (`417`) and its height (`37`) and get `744 - 417 - 37 = 290`.

Note that the rectangle doesn't have any transforms and doesn't belong to a group.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the whole SVG.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I've shared it - see the link titled *Inkscape file* in the first sentence of the question.

Comment: If the select tool is chosen (as it is in the image), then the X, Y, Width, and Height of the selection is in the information bar (which is under the toolbar). I'm not sure what you want but you should be able to calculate it from this information.

Comment: @shawnhcorey I want to understand, how exactly Inkscape calculates the number `596.654` (y coordinate of the rectangle displayed in the toolbar).

Comment: Y value of rectangle +/- half the stroke width.

Comment: What Paul mean was that It would be helpful if you posted the whole SVG in the question itself. i.e. not as a link.

Comment: The width and height of the svg element is in mm.  Maybe there is a computation somewhere in the app that is computing pixels vs mm based on the display size. btw, the rect is in a <g> which has been transformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplified version of your SVG with only the relevant information included:

```
<svg width="297mm" height="210mm"
     viewBox="0 0 1052.3622 744.09448">
  <g transform="translate(0,-308.26772)">
    <rect x="216.1537" y="417.34927"
          width="385.25827" height="37.859257"
          style="stroke-width:1;"
   />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Despite what you thought, there **is** a transform in there (in the group).

SVG internal coordinates have their origin in the top left.  Whereas Inkscape displays a converted value relative to the more normal origin at bottom left.  The displayed value also takes into account the stroke width.

Your rectangle is drawn (internal coords) at

```
y = rectY + translateY
  = 417.34927 - 308.26772
  = 109.08155
```

The page has a height of 744.09448. So the displayed ccoordinate will be:

```
y = pageHeight - rectY - rectH - strokeWidth/2
  = 744.09448 - 109.08155 - 37.859257 - 0.5
  = 596.653673
```